# Crontab to run python script that uses a virtual environment

Tags: cron, miniconda

Currently I have a python script that uses a virtual environment called myenv. The command to run the script in terminal is the following:

```
cd env && source activate env && bin/env-dev python ~/Documents/test/ingest.py
```

When I tried setting this up in crontab, I kept getting an error with "command not found." 
In cron tab I have tried a few different options:

1) Using a bash (the final piece is to write the errors to a text file). This has actually worked for other scripts in the file path that do not need to source activate myenv. So the problem exists when I add in source activate myenv.

```
* * * * * bash -c 'cd env && source activate env && bin/env-dev python ~/Documents/test/ingest.py' >> ~/test_cron.txt 2>&1
```

[screenshot of terminal with the bash command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdHo.png)

2) No bash

```
* * * * * cd env && source activate env && bin/env-dev python ~/Documents/test/ingest.py
```

3) I have also tried adding in a PATH=/Users/mattzerweck/miniconda3/envs/myenv at the top of the crontab but that has not successfully executed the bash.

Does any one have a solution for this? I haven't seemed to find a solution that has worked online and need this script to run automatically every morning at 5am. (currently every minute for testing purposes)

Comment: Which is the part of this that is causing `command not found`? Is it `bin/env-dev`? Also, the command in more recent versions of conda is `conda activate` rather than `source activate`. You'll need to make sure that the conda executable is on the PATH of the user who runs the cron job.

Comment: Also, does that command work when your user runs it?

Comment: 2) works in my command line, so ya it works when the user runs it. The part that causes 'command not found' when I run the crontab is when I include source activate env. I am running the cron from my local and just need to figure out how to get the second option i mentioned able to work on the cron.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that worked. Has to set a path and shell up top before the commands. Cron wasnt pulling my correct file path.

Comment: Can you past some code to show how you solved this?